React Native Build Fails from missing native module gradle file
I tried to run ./gradlew clean and ./gradlew dependencies in the /android directory on RN 0.76.0 but it fails with this error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:

Settings file 'C:\Users\Username\AppName\android\settings.gradle' line: 17

* What went wrong:

A problem occurred evaluating settings 'Waypoint'.

> Could not read script 'C:\Users\Username\AppName\native_modules.gradle' as it does not exist.

I do not want to downgrade the RN version since it will cause problems with other RN packages, Thank you :)
I actually tried to run ./gradlew clean to clear unused file in order to rebuild the app with react-native run-android, but that fails aswell.
P.S. I'm using Expo, but I'm pretty sure that won't affect the errors that I'm currently having.
